# Google chart api, same options, different data array make bug

Tags: javascript, google-api

I am using line chart via google chart api, and stuck with a problem.
When i am using arrayToDataTable everything works fine and looks okay.

https://jsfiddle.net/Ljz49gqb/

But when i am filling data object, and populate it with data needed, it's being like cut from the right side.

https://jsfiddle.net/Ljz49gqb/1/

Options in this examples, are the same

```
        var options = {
            height: 245,
            width: '100%',
            chartArea: {top: 15, left: 30, width: '100%', height: 190},
            areaOpacity: 0.1,
            tooltip: {trigger: 'both'},
            legend: 'none',
            pointSize: 5,
            hAxis: {
                format: 'MM-dd',
                gridlines: {
                    color: '#fff',
                    count: 365 /* \_(ツ)_/ */
                },
                textStyle: {
                    fontSize: 11
                }
            },
            vAxis: {
                gridlines: {
                    color: '#dedede',
                    count: 5
                },
                viewWindow: {
                    min: 0
                },
                textStyle: {
                    fontSize: 11
                },
                baselineColor: 'dedede'
            }
        };
```

p.s. 100% width must left, because page is dynamic and used in mobile.

**UPDATE**
Displays bad even so

https://jsfiddle.net/Ljz49gqb/2/

**UPDATE**

It was not about dataTable, it was about Date type in google chart api, and 100% width. (Just to help find this topic in google)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with

```
    chartWrapWidth = document.getElementById('chart_div').offsetWidth;
    options.chartArea.width = chartWrapWidth - 45;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ljz49gqb/4/